# gevent install error: `next' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: python, gevent, python-requests

I'm trying to install gevent on RHEL 4.8 with the dev version of python 2.7.2.
I've installed libevent2-2.0.10 (dev version) and greenlet.

When I do sudo pip install gevent, I get the following error:

```
gevent/core.c: In function `__pyx_pf_6gevent_4core_17http_request_base_12get_input_headers':
gevent/core.c:10388: warning: implicit declaration of function `TAILQ_FIRST'
gevent/core.c:10388: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
gevent/core.c:10494: warning: implicit declaration of function `TAILQ_NEXT'
gevent/core.c:10494: error: `next' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Does anybody know what the source of this error could be? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Gevent? Which version of Cython? What's inside core.c around the failing line? It compiles happily on my Ubuntu box, but I can't find any `TAILQ_NEXT` in generated `core.c`...

Answer (score 0):

try to install libevent-1.4.13-stable, that worked for me